# Why "TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX" warning in JBoss server.log

Tags: jboss, timeout

I am using **Hibernate 3.6.0** with **JBoss 6.0-Final** release and my Database is **MS-SQL Server 2008**.
I have to fetch employee data from LDAP server and insert those into database - the count of LDAP entries are 180,000 or more.
I am using **bean managed transaction** because using **CMT** my transaction ***never*** gets committed (because of high volumn of insert).

The logic is: in a while-loop I am keep on fetching & creating entries in database using JPA (Hibernate). Thus I am having a long series of fetch-create activities as part of a stateless EJB api.
I am invoking entityManager.flush()/clear() and **commiting transaction** after processing **every 20** records.

I am getting following **WARN message** in JBoss Serevr.log after I have inserted 40,000 records.
Not sure if it is really an warning or error?

Though I get this error, the server still runs and continues with inserting new records in DB.

Can anyone suggest if I am doing something wrong? Or what causes this error?

Is there a way to **increase the EJB timeout**?

```
16:52:49,690 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] ARJUNA-12117 TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff105966b8:126a:4db9fc0a:a4 in state  RUN
16:52:49,691 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] ARJUNA-12121 TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,jboss] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff105966b8:126a:4db9fc0a:a4
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Increasing a **higher** `TransactionTimeout` value (like 3600 seconds), I do not see such warning anymore. So looks like I need to set a `higher TransactionTimeout` value for such kind of workflow.

Comment: I found the reason and it is possible to increase the timeout value thru annotation using Api level.

Answer (score 15):

[This website](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-transactions-jta-using-jboss-as7-wildfly) summarizes a couple of more ways for changing the transaction timeout of jboss. For example, you can specify it in your standalone.xml configuration file as a subsystem like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:3.0">
    <core-environment>
        <process-id><uuid/></process-id>
    </core-environment>
    <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
    <coordinator-environment default-timeout="<your timeout value here>"/>
</subsystem>
```

Alternative adjust the transaction timeout prameter via the jboss admin platform under subsystems->transaction->Time Out

Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Now I changed my answer so that some of the content is also shown here. Hopefully that will be more appropriate as an answer.

Comment: Or using Wildfly web-interface: http://localhost:9990/console/index.html#transactions - Edit - Default Timeout

Comment: The value of "default-timeout" is seconds.

Answer (score 6):

As per your own comment (but to give an actual example), if you need to increase a transaction time-out you can use an annotation on the method of whichever class defines your transactional boundary (usually a "facade" implmentation).

For example, using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

```
@Transactional(timeout = 600) // value is in seconds
```

It sounds like you need this for a one-off data conversion task rather than day-to-day production code so increasing the time-out is probably justifiable. Otherwise it would be worth considering batching the processing into smaller chunks and making each one a unique transaction which is expected to complete within the default time-out for your system.